# configuring Session in codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Hello i have been working with codeigniter v2.2 now that i have started using codeigniter v3.0 i get problem in making the session for authentication of the user account i would like to get help on how i can make it work.

The following is the code in the controller.

```
public function validation(){

    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');


    $this->load->model('user_model');

    $query = $this->user_model->validate();


    if($query) //if credential validated

    {
        $data1 = array(
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'is_logged_in' => true );

        $this->session->set_userdata($data1);

        redirect('users_area/user_is_in');


    }
    else{
        $this->login();
    }


}
```

The user_model code is as follows

```
 function validate(){

    $this->db->where('username',$this->input->post('username'));

    $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));


    $query = $this->db->get('tbl_users');

    if($query->num_rows == 1){

        $this->session->set_userdata(array('authorized' => true));

        return true;

    }

}
```

and finally  there is a controller called users_area which is the one that
check if the session has been set then gives the user access to the page this has always been working in the previous codeigniter versions

users_area controller

```
function user_is_in(){


    $is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');

    if($is_logged_in != ""){

        $this->members();

    }else {

        redirect('verify/signin');
        die();
        //session has to be altered bro
    }


}



function members()
{

    redirect('verify/users_mahali');

}
```

Comment: are you sure you add session library

Comment: add this `$this->load->library('session');`

Comment: Auto load the session library best can you add your session config

Comment: Try not to use MD5 For passwords very unsecure,

Comment: yes i have added in both the autoload and i have also add in the class @monace19 it is not working

Comment: I have tried not to use the MD5 and still its not working

Comment: and the funny thing is i am not getting any error when i put the credentials in the form it just refresh @monace19

Comment: i wonder maybe there is a different configuration needed to be done in the config file ?   @wolfgang1983

Comment: The sessions config in codeigniter 3 are different to what is in Ci2 versions http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

**In Model**

```
function validate(){

    $this->db->where('username',$this->input->post('username'));
    $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));
    $query = $this->db->get('tbl_users');
    $result = $query->result_array();

    $count = count($result);
    if(empty(count)){

        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }

}
```

**In Controller**

```
public function validation(){

    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->model('user_model');

    $result = $this->user_model->validate();


    if($result == false)
    {
        # Invalid user
        $this->login();
    }
    else{

        # valid use

        $data1 = array(
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'is_logged_in' => true 
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data1);
        redirect('users_area/user_is_in');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Abdulla i will get bask to you thanks for the support

Comment: happy to help you :)